# Ampersand is omitted with SendKeys() in Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, jquery-ui-autocomplete

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6074

I am using Selenium and jQuery UI Autocomplete. I am trying to send a word with the ampersand in it but the ampersand is omitted. If I type in the ampersand manually on the interface, it works fine. The problem occurs specifically with Firefox but not with Chrome.

I noticed this was raised as a bug in Selenium 2 years ago (2013) but there doesn't seem to be any update on it.

A workaround to this problem which was suggested in the above link was something like this:

```
textBox.sendKeys("R/&d")
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT);
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT);
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
```

This is not an option as the String could be dynamic and this would require knowing the exact position of the ampersand. It's a really unnecessary hack! It's not like we are dealing with Internet Explorer here.

Is there really no solution for this after 2 years?

Comment: Did you mean to type `R\&d` instead?

Comment: Have you tried using `&amp;` instead of just `&`? So, for example, "R&amp;d"...

Comment: Yes, tried everything in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using javascript to enter the text, something like(in C#):

```
    public void SendKeysUsingJS(IWebElement element, string text)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor exec = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        exec.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = '" + text + "';", element);
    }
```

Obviously driver is your webdriver instance.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it won't generate any of the key events that `sendKeys` generates. In many cases it matters because what is being tested is precisely whether the key events are properly handled.

Comment: Could be used on conjunction with normal sendkeys method just for ampersands. It's not explicitly stated that the key events are needed just that there is a need to enter and ampersand.